# What is an Uncopyrightable Word?™

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

If a phrase has a certain property, I call it an Uncopyrightable Word™.

In each of the sentences below, one word is an Uncopyrightable Word™ and one is not.

The sentences are for context only, and do not affect whether a word is an Uncopyrightable Word™.

> 1. The forecast says it's going to (**SNOW** / **RAIN**) tomorrow.
> 2. Your explanations always tend towards (**HYPERBOLE** / **EXAGGERATION**).
> 3. The ideal political system is a (**DEMOCRACY** / **REPUBLIC**).
> 4. The answer to your question is (**YES** / **NO**).
> 5. His (**NEIGHBOURLY** / **FRIENDLY**) advice was well-received.
> 6. I (**CERTAINLY** / **DEFINITELY**) don't think this puzzle is difficult.
> 7. The (**DUKE** / **BARON**) had very good manners.
> 8. The team worked with great (**SYNERGY** / **RECIPROCITY**).
> 9. The winter (**FESTIVAL** / **CELEBRATION**) is one of the high points of the year.
> 10. My favourite composer is (**BACH** / **BEETHOVEN**).

**What makes a word an Uncopyrightable Word™?**

Comment: Five minutes! :D

Comment: A word that is property of the public domain?

Comment: @Goinghamateur As I mentioned below, I considered calling it a Generic Word™ (and a Public Domain Word™), but I figured that would be a little too obscure.

Comment: That would certainly doozy it up, I would be astonished if someone solved it and then again this place blows my mind every fifth puzzle... not©™?

Comment: \*cough\* Since words can't be copyrighted in any jurisdiction I'm aware of... \*cough\*

Comment: If it's uncopyrightable, how can it be ™ed? :-P

Comment: @randal'thor The words in the puzzle are Uncopyrightable. That doesn't meant the category isn't. Also, trademark and copyright are not the same. :P

Comment: Fun Fact: Uncopyrightable is the longest word in the English language that contains no repeated characters.

Comment: @Dave That was the main reason for using it here.  But technically, there are longer ones.  See http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17667 .

Answer (score 25, accepted):

An Uncopyrightable Word™ is one that...

> consists only of letters in the word UNCOPYRIGHTABLE.

So the Uncopyrightable Word™s are...

> RAIN, HYPERBOLE, REPUBLIC, NO, NEIGHBOURLY, CERTAINLY, BARON, RECIPROCITY, CELEBRATION, and BACH.

Comment: I thought the answer would be found quickly, but not *that* quickly!  Good job!  
  
I thought about calling it a Generic Word™ instead, but I thought that would be a little *too* vague...

Comment: I knew "Uncopyrightable" had all unique letters, so my first thought was to check the letter patterns. After a few quick find+replaces, the pattern was obvious. Great puzzle though!

Comment: just beat me, @Deusovi

Comment: Legend tells of a puzzle that someone was able to answer before Deusovi, but all historical records have been lost and only a myth remains.

Comment: @Goinghamateur [Found it!](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16987)  :)

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain: In my defense, it seemed to me that using borders was cheating.

Comment: I so would have gotten this if I had not had to drive home from work immediately after seeing this puzzle! At least, that is what I will tell myself. :)

Comment: I guessed the answer just from seeing the title :-)

Comment: I thought the answer was your gut-feeling stereotypical reaction answer. I got all of them right except for #8.

Comment: @Deusovi: Yep, UNCOPYRIGHTABLE is well-known as being one of the longest English words that has no repeated letters. Another (lesser-known) word is DERMATOGLYPHICS.

Answer (score 11):

An uncopyrightable word is a word which

> can be spelled using only letters in 'uncopyrightable', so
>  RAIN, HYPERBOLE, REPUBLIC, NO, NEIGHBOURLY, CERTAINLY, RECIPROCITY, CELEBRATION, and BACH.